# Get latlng of the map when panned or zoomed

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to get the lat lng of the map center when it's dragged, panned or zoomed. I want to get the instant update of lat lng of the map's center the moment I drag, pan or zoom the map. I am using the following code

```
map.on('focus', function(e) {
   console.log("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
});
```

I get the error `Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`. But the code works when I use `click`instead of `focus`.

This can be easily done with google map using

```
map.addListener('get_center',function(){
  console.log("Lat, Lng:"+ map.center.lat()","+ map.center.lng())
})
```

Does anyone know a proper way to do it in the leaflet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [getCenter()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-getcenter) method to get the lat and lng at anytime. Use the zoom and drag events as you prefer. [Refer the documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#event). Make sure you use getCenter() as below

```
map.on('dragend', function(e) {
    console.log('Lat: ' +  map.getCenter().lat + ' Lng: ' + map.getCenter().lng);
});
```

Comment: `moveend` can also be useful - it fires whenever the centre of the map has moved either with a drag or programmatically